# C# Reusing Logic for Different Property Names

Tags: c#

I have the following coverage class:

```
public class Coverages
{
    public double? Deductible1 { get; set; }
    public double? Deductible2 { get; set; }
    public double? Deductible3 { get; set; }
    public bool IsCoverage { get; set; }
    public int? Limit1 { get; set; }
    public int? Limit2 { get; set; }
    public int? Limit3 { get; set; }
    public string DeductType1 { get; set; }
    public string DeductType2 { get; set; }
    public string DeductType3 { get; set; }
}
```

I also have the following logic:

```
if (coverage.Deductible1.HasValue)
{
    var coverageValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(coverage.DeductType1)
                                ? string.Format("{0}/{1}", coverage.DeductType1, coverage.Deductible1)
                                : coverage.Deductible1.Value.ToString();

    coverages.Add(new CoverageDto
    {
        Name = string.Format("{0} - {1}", coverage.CoverageCode, "All Peril"),
        Value = coverageValue
    });
}
```

I would like to reuse this logic for `Deductible2`, `Deductible3` which will of course use its respective `DeductTypes` (ie. `DeductType1` for `Deductible1`). How do I parameterize the properties of the class to reuse this logic or is there a better of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Deductible`, `Limit` and `DeductType` seem very related, and should be grouped into a class/struct:

```
public class DeductibleInfo {
    public double? Deductible { get; set; }
    public int? Limit { get; set; }
    public string DeductType { get; set; }

    // Constructors...
    // ...
}
```

Now `Coverage` can have an array of `DeductibleInfo`s:

```
public DeductibleInfo[] Deductibles { get; } = new DeductibleInfo[] {
    new DeductibleInfo(),
    new DeductibleInfo(),
    new DeductibleInfo()
};
```

Now, you can easily extract a method for your logic:

```
public void SomeMethod(Coverage coverage, int deductibleIndex) {
    var deductibleInfo = coverage.Deductibles[deductibleIndex];
    if (deductibleInfo.Deductible.HasValue)
    {
        var coverageValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(deductibleInfo.DeductType)
                                    ? string.Format("{0}/{1}", deductibleInfo.DeductType, deductibleInfo.Deductible)
                                    : deductibleInfo.Deductible.Value.ToString();
    
        coverages.Add(new CoverageDto
        {
            Name = string.Format("{0} - {1}", coverage.CoverageCode, "All Peril"),
            Value = coverageValue
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're after a simple rule you could consider that "Any time you have a property name with a number on the end of it it's a candidate for backing it with an array so you can address it programmatically"

```
public class Coverages
{
    private double?[3] deductibles = new double?[3];
    public double? Deductible1 { get => deductibles[0]; set => deductibles[0] = value; }
    public double? Deductible2 { get => deductibles[1]; set => deductibles[1] = value; }
    
    ...
```

Then you can refer to them programmatically, for example;

```
for(int x = 0; x<deductibles.Length; x++)
{
  if (coverage.deductibles[x].HasValue)
  {
    var coverageValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(coverage.deductTypes[x])
                                ? string.Format("{0}/{1}", coverage.deductTypes[x], coverage.deductibles[x])
                                : coverage.deductibles[x].Value.ToString();

    coverages.Add(new CoverageDto
    {
        Name = string.Format("{0} - {1}", coverage.CoverageCode, "All Peril"),
        Value = coverageValue
    });
  }
}
```

So if you ever find yourself wishing you could refer to some similar named properties that have some pattern to their name, you probably need a collection of them